# I can't turn off my iPhone after building Project. What to do?

Tags: xcode4.5

I am building a project. Everything fine. Then I installed that on my iPhone.

My iPhone stack at the front screen and that's it.

Pressing the power off button for long doesn't work.

The xcode says Could not launch  "Application Name". permission denied.

Should I just wait till iPhone run out of battery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to restart iPhone using the instructions here: 
http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/assistant/phone/#section_1

"To reset iPhone, press and hold the Sleep/Wake button and the Home button at the same time for at least 10 seconds, until the Apple logo appears."

Comment: What works is I wait till battery run out. Will use this next time

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone5's display became so large that I could not use it. When I tried to reset the size just like I do on my MacPro, it didn't work. So, I thought I'd restart it, but when I pressed the top button, the screen with the "slide to power off" came on and it was not possible to complete the task. It was frustrating and I thought of taking the battery out and putting it in again, but then I thought to try sliding the bar with my stylus pen and it worked immediately.